# Problemas con Lazyload

Tags: angular, hosting, localhost, lazy-loading

Tengo este problema, en el que llevo bastante tiempo tratando de resolver.

Tengo un proyecto que utiliza `lazyload` porque esta dividido en varios módulos. El error que tengo es que mientras estoy en modo desarrollo, el `lazyload` funciona perfecto y las rutas hijas son cargadas en el momento en que se les necesita, cuando compilo la aplicación `ng build` que la subo al hosting **IONOS** o la prueba en servidor web local es que aparece el problema y me devuelve un **404**

Les comparto el código de los ficheros de rutas.

app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { InicioComponent } from './web/pages/inicio/inicio.component';
import { PromoActualComponent } from './web/components/promo-actual/promo-actual.component';

import { AuthGuardGuard } from './guards/auth-guard.guard';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'auth',
    loadChildren: () => import('./auth/auth.module').then((m) => m.AuthModule),
  },
  {
    path: 'admin',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./admin/admin.module').then((m) => m.AdminModule),
    canLoad: [AuthGuardGuard],
    canActivate: [AuthGuardGuard],
  },
  {
    path: 'cliente',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./cliente/cliente.module').then((m) => m.ClienteModule),
    canLoad: [AuthGuardGuard],
    canActivate: [AuthGuardGuard],
  },
  { path: '', component: InicioComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: '**', component: NoFoundInicioComponent },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { anchorScrolling: 'enabled' })],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

auth-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { LoginComponent } from './pages/login/login.component';
import { RegistroComponent } from './pages/registro/registro.component';
import { ConfirmacionComponent } from './pages/confirmacion/confirmacion.component';
import { RestartPasswordComponent } from './pages/restart-password/restart-password.component';
import { ChangePasswordComponent } from './pages/change-password/change-password.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    children: [
      { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
      { path: 'registro', component: RegistroComponent },
      { path: 'confirmacion', component: ConfirmacionComponent },
      { path: 'confirmacion/:id', component: ConfirmacionComponent },
      { path: 'restablecer-contrasena', component: RestartPasswordComponent },
      { path: 'change-contrasena/:id', component: ChangePasswordComponent },
      { path: '**', redirectTo: 'login' },
    ],
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AuthRoutingModule {}
```

Este es el log de compilación de la aplicación, donde se muestra que se crearon todos los módulos a ser cargados con `lazyload`

```
Build at: 2022-04-21T03:41:52.440Z - Hash: 079d5087b5c8e219 - Time: 28704ms
PS C:\Users\UCACUE\Desktop\angular\butterflyNails> ng build
✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.
✔ Copying assets complete.
✔ Index html generation complete.

Initial Chunk Files           | Names                                 |  Raw Size | Estimated Transfer Size
main.b3f4f3447604cb6c.js      | main                                  |   2.13 MB |               451.70 kB
styles.c5869b13babbc4c0.css   | styles                                | 456.92 kB |                38.71 kB
scripts.7b3879f5b661c7f4.js   | scripts                               | 402.51 kB |                99.37 kB
polyfills.7cbc37b7a83ef6d0.js | polyfills                             |  36.24 kB |                11.52 kB
runtime.28b93f1ae0f080f6.js   | runtime                               |   3.09 kB |                 1.49 kB

                              | Initial Total                         |   3.01 MB |               602.78 kB

Lazy Chunk Files              | Names                                 |  Raw Size | Estimated Transfer Size
800.89436b5c73ac58f4.js       | admin-admin-module                    |  33.56 kB |                 7.82 kB
83.343623583407f9e2.js        | auth-auth-module                      |  20.04 kB |                 3.94 kB
462.9b1d9cc4cf5c9168.js       | cliente-cliente-module                |  15.41 kB |                 3.79 kB
common.a43f5fb54e0d8120.js    | common                                |   6.48 kB |                 1.86 kB
```

He aquí el error que me devuelve el servidor al intentar cargar la ruta de */auth* en mi server **local** y en el server de **IONOS** https://butterflynails.me/auth

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la versión de Angular que uso

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

creo que tu problema no es Angular, me parece que es el virtualhost de Apache que estas usando. Las SPAs o Apps compiladas de Js no corren del mismo modo que las apps hechas en php (wordpres, prestashop.... etc) necesitan una configuracion especial de server para correr bien.

Antes de implementar verifiquemos que si es esto, instala http-server, despues le das build a tu aplicacion, este compilado quedara en la carpeta /dist. Entramos ahi y corremos htt-server:

```
npm i http-server
cd ./dist
http-server
```

tu App quedara desplegada en localhost:8080 ve alli y verifica si las rutas funcionan... en caso de que esten funcionando, el error es en la configuracion de virtual host de tu server remoto.

Para solucionar esto en apache ve a:

```
cd /etc/apache2/sites-available
```

buscas el archivo de configuracion de tu virtualhost y lo editas

```
sudo nano miarchivo.conf
```

dentro usa esta configuracion:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

*puse imagen porque este modelo de archivo jode el editor de texto de aqui.

Espero ayude esta solucion.

Comment: gracias por contestar, tengo otra aplicación corriendo en el mismo hosting y creada de la misma manera que carga las rutas sin problema https://miconsultorio.codeqba.com/ la diferencia entre ambos proyectos esta en el fichero `tsconfig.json`  en el consultorio en `compilerOption:{}` uso `"lib": ["es2018", "dom"]` y en el proyecto en cuestion `"lib": ["es2021", "dom"]` no se si existira cambios importantes a realizar para la compilación en algún fichero de configuración

Comment: Tienes razón, estuve revisando el ` .htaccess` de otro sitio que cree y logre la solución, gracias por tu idea

Answer (score 1):

Con el aporte de @julio-daza publico el `.htaccess` que soluciona el problema

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /

  # Redirection of requests to index.html
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
  RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
  # Redirect all non-file routes to index.html
  RewriteRule ^(?!.*\.).*$ index.html [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

en caso de tener la aplicación en un subdirectorio del dominio principal solo es necesario cambiar el  `RewriteBase /` por  `RewriteBase /subdirectorio/`